# Oracle 12C Database default Listener

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-net-services

I Have installed Oracle 12c r2 database software only on RHEL7 ( AWS EC2 instance). Then I created a database DB1 using DBCA. At the end of DBCA when it prompted for the listener I let it create the default 'LISTENER',  Started the listener and the database and database registered automatically with the default 'LISTENER' as expected. Also verified my listener is started using lsnrctl.

Question: When I start netca, the option to reconfigure the existing listener is grayed out. When means netca is not able to recognize existing Listener. 
How can I get a handle to default listener to either change the port, protocol or just to delete the  listener. I tried netmgr and it can't see the listener as well.

Comment: The tools might not be finding your ORACLE_HOME... You could just edit `listener.ora`, which is what those tools do. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/listener.htm#NETRF292

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Since this is a  default listener, the listener.ora is blank. I tried to start netca by manually setting the TNS_ADMIN to $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin . It still didn't find the listener 'LISTENER' that is already started.

Comment: So this is what I did  to resolve the issue -
I manually created an entry for the listener 'LISTNER' in listener.ora. This time when I started the netca it was able to detect the running listener. I needed to modify the listener to replace localhost by actual machine name. Since there was no entry in listener.ora I didn’t know where the configuration is for the default listener.

Thanks again for your tip!

Answer (score 0):

I manually created an entry for the listener 'LISTNER' in listener.ora. This time when I started the netca it was able to detect the running listener. I needed to modify the listener to replace localhost by actual machine name. Since there was no entry in listener.ora I didn’t know where the configuration is for the default listener. Thanks again for your tip! –